# Jackson JSON schema generation of complex Java type

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I just downloaded the latest jackson-module-jsonSchema (2.2.0) and was wondering if anyone might be able to provide an example for generating a schema for a complex Java type (e.g. a type containing some `SubObject` or `List<SubObject>`)?

I was able to create a "flat" schema successfully with the following:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper(); 
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
m.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(m.constructType(RuleSet.class), visitor); 
JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema(); 
return jsonSchema;
```

Comment: Can you show definition of `RuleSet` and referenced types? That'd make it easier to see what gets generated.

Comment: @StaxMan So I realized that the properties that I had annotated with the JsonPoperty annotation were returning instances of Object[] instead of List<MyObject>. Jackson, obviously, couldn't determine anything more at that point so it left it at the property name. When I switched to List<MyObject> Jackson acted as expected and filled in the schema for MyObject.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that would explain it. Although would be nice if there was a placeholder of sorts to indicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in what sense? You should be able to just generate schema using root type, and referenced types should generate schema definitions recursively.

Comment: In my example above the RuleSet class is a complex type but the resulting schema was flat; There were no schemas generated for the referenced types. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. My understanding is that referenced types should be defined within schema as well. But I have not used this schema extensively.